# finding folders containing but not starting with a . (dot)

Tags: linux, command-line

How do I find all folders containing a . in the foldename? I've tried the following, but it listed all folders, not what I wanted;
*find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -ipath "*.*"*

I seem to have a lot of folders named somethign like this; `Brain.Dead.1990.1080p.BluRay.x264-HD4U[rarbg]` and thats just plain ugly for me. I'd like to list them and then edit their names to something more readable.
Any clues?

Comment: Is your question about finding them (title) or renaming them (body)?

Comment: Just finding them for now

Comment: The biggest issue is that you're matching `path` not `name` - *every* path will match `.` when the starting point of your search is `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another find whitout regex

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*.*' ! -name '.*'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*.*'
```

Reports any directory with `.` in their name including `.`, `./user/.config`, `./.foo.d` and `./.foo/bar.baz`.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '?*.*'
```

Would look for `.` in the part after the first character, so it would match on `.foo.d` but not `.config` or `.`.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '[!.]*.*'
```

Would omit hidden dirs (the ones whose name starts with `.`) but would still find non-hidden dirs inside hidden dirs (would find `./.foo/foo.bar`).

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name '.?*' -prune -o -type d -name '?*.*' -print
```

Would not traverse nor report hidden directory.

The only non-standard part in there is the `-maxdepth 2` which you're already using. The standard equivalent would be:

```
find . -name '.?*' -prune -o \
   \( ! -path './*/*' -o -prune \) \
   -type d -name '?*.*' -print
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression, if your version of `find` supports that:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -regex '.*/[^./][^/]*\.[^/]*'
```

This matches any directory (with a maximum depth of two) whose name starts with any character other than “.” and contains a “.” in any other position.